# Middleware defined before model definition, cascade delete failing, appears middleware gets bypassed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is what I have in my file. What I want to do is that when an `Author` document is removed, all his `Book` documents should also be removed. I initially experimented with serial middleware with error handlers wired in but no errors were being logged, `Author` was being removed but his `Book`s were not.

Then I tried parallel middleware under the assumption that `remove()` won't be triggered until all its pre-middleware has completed but that doesn't seem to be the case. `Author` is still being removed but `Book`s are not, and no errors are being logged:

```
//...

var Book = require('./book-model'');

AuthorSchema.pre('remove', true, function(next, done) {
    Book.remove({author: this._id}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        }
        done();
    });
    next();
});

AuthorSchema.statics.deleteAuthor = function(authorId, callback) {
    var Author = mongoose.model('Author');
    Author.remove({_id: authorId}, callback);
};

// ...

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema);
```

So I'm thinking that the middleware is being bypassed otherwise, considering the number of variations that I've tried, I'd have seen at least a couple of errors to indicate that the middleware is indeed being triggered. Unluckily, I just can't seem to put a finger on what I'm doing wrong.

Please advise.

Comment: Is the `Book.remove()` even being called? Maybe check with `Books.pre('remove'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'remove'` middleware only runs when the `remove` *instance* method is called ([`Model#remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove)), not the class method ([`Model.remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)).  This is akin to how `'save'` middleware is called on `save` but not on `update`.

So you'd need to rewrite your `deleteAuthor` method to something like:

```
AuthorSchema.statics.deleteAuthor = function(authorId, callback) {
    this.findById(authorId, function(err, author) {
        if (author) {
            author.remove(callback);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried what you've suggested and I'm now receiving all errors that come from the middleware. When I first got an `Object Book has no method remove` error, I substituted `remove()` for `find()....remove()` then finally attempted a custom method `deleteAuthorBooks` defined on the `BookSchema` but none worked, returning the same error. What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: If it doesn't have a `remove` method, `Book` must not be the `Book` model that you think it is.

Comment: That's strange because I've successfully used the functionality contained in `book-model.js` in other controllers and models. But thanks anyway. I'll get through this with time.